# Is Nautilus elementary compatible?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus-elementary

Has anybody tried installing nautilus elementary in 11.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm running 11.04 and nautilus elementary - no problems here.
If you do encounter any problems with NE, please report (a) bug(s) on nautilus-elementary's bug tracker on launchpad.

Comment: Same here. Works just as well as in 10.10

Comment: Has someone tried it with 11.04 64 bit?

Comment: @eddy147 me... :)